# Einstein submanifold of Einstein manifold - References

Tags: riemannian-geometry, manifolds, curvature, ricci-curvature

Is there any work in which the conditions under which an Einstein manifold admits an Einstein submanifold are studied?

If yes, can you give me the references?

Comment: I don't have a reference for this specific question, but the book "Einstein manifolds" by Besse is usually a standard reference book on the topic.

Comment: This is a bit vague. Are you looking for a local or global existence theorem? Any assumptions on codimension or topology?

Comment: Thank to both of you for the answers. I was looking for a theorem (if exists) indicating the conditions for which an Einstein manifold can admit an Einstein submanifold

Comment: It seems the following paper has some such theorems: http://www.pphmj.com/abstract/3156.htm

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems interesting

Comment: The doubt arises from this question: if I have an Einstein manifold, is there always (at least) an Einstein manifold that can be a sub-manifold of the first?

Comment: I think yes, but are there any specific conditions?